# HDMI trouble shooting samsung tv

Tags: hdmi

I plugged my Pi into a Samsung smart TV and got no signal. In the config.txt file I uncommented hdmi safe mode this gave me a picture but 640x480 and I want 1920x1080.

Could anyone give me any ideas how I can get this working.

Regards

Comment: btw tvservice -s and tvservice -n show me that the tv sees the pi

Comment: same problem. it worked directly after i switched HDMI Cable to a different port

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the cable! Brand new out the pack but I switched it for a different one and it worked.

Comment: Could you mark this as answered?